# error java app Android

Tags: java, android, linux

I have a problem and I do not understand the reason why. I'm working on Android Studio on Linux. The bitmap size is 10x10 pixels. I searched in google, but it gave me nothing. I would be grateful if someone could help me.

This problem is something with this:

```
"Bitmap suweren = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.suweren);"
```

and this is **error log:**

```
"12-30 07:16:36.125 9336-9336/com.example.szczesciarz.sawa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.szczesciarz.sawa, PID: 9336
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.szczesciarz.sawa/com.example.szczesciarz.sawa.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
    at com.example.szczesciarz.sawa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-30 07:21:36.565 9336-9336/com.example.szczesciarz.sawa I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9336 SIG: 9"
```

Main Activity_code:

```
package com.example.szczesciarz.sawa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

GameView code:

```
package com.example.szczesciarz.sawa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

class GameView extends View{
public GameView(Context context){
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas ){
    Bitmap suweren = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Context.getResources(), R.drawable.suweren);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(suweren, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

Thanks):-

Comment: Please post the code for that activity. From the log, the issue has to do with the ToolbarWidgetWrapper

Comment: The error seems to be in some other part of your code. Share the code to solve it.

Comment: this is code for GameView.java

Comment: package com.example.szczesciarz.sawa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

class GameView extends View{
    public GameView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Bitmap suweren = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.suweren);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(suweren, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

Comment: forgive so illegibly , until I started here Account.

Comment: Please add your activity code to the question, and not in a comment.

Comment: @Koles Post your code please

Comment: MAin_activity code package com.example.szczesciarz.sawa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

Comment: @Koles add this in your question section

Comment: Guess you are accessing ActionBar in MainActivity at line 19. It may return null if you dont set the style properly. Check that.

Comment: what do you think `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` should do ?

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar cannot be found :

> Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

So when you call

> setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

You have a NullPointerException at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)

try to remove setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your layout file contains toolbar or you have included the toolbar layout.

This exception occurs when your layout file does not contain the id, so android is unable to get the view from that id and returns null when you call findViewById(R.id.toolbar);